# If statement inside for loop - python-docx-template jinja

Tags: python, jinja2, python-docx

I am using Python-Docx-Template to dynamically create address labels that can be printed on Avery labels.  I have found the correct table template in MS Word and have inserted a FOR loop to go through the addresses.  There are 3 addresses per line, so I have set up the code like this:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

tpl=DocxTemplate('templates/address_labels.docx')

context = {
    'tbl_contents' : [
    {'addrs':[
        {'addr_count':1,'first':'Peyton','last':'Manning','addr1':'123 Cherry St.','city':'Denver','state':'CO','zip':'12345'},
        {'addr_count':2,'first':'Patrick','last':'Mahomes','addr1':'123 KC BBQ Blvd','city':'Kansas City','state':'MO','zip':'12345'},
        {'addr_count':3,'first':'Tom','last':'Brady','addr1':'123 New England Cir','city':'Boston','state':'MA','zip':'12345'}]},
    {'addrs':[
        {'addr_count':1,'first':'Drew','last':'Brees','addr1':'123 Nola Way','city':'New Orleans','state':'LA','zip':'12345'},
        {'addr_count':2,'first':'Phillip','last':'Rivers','addr1':'123 Beachside Dr.','city':'Los Angeles','state':'CA','zip':'12345'},
        {'addr_count':3,'first':'Kyler','last':'Murray','addr1':'123 Dusty Rhoads Dr','city':'Phoenix','state':'AZ','zip':'12345'}
        ]}
    ]
}
tpl.render(context)
tpl.save('output/addr_labels.docx')
```

My word Template is:

[image]

I'm doing the table this way because the Avery address labels have the thin table cell in between the larger cell where the address goes.  This helps with formatting.  If I remove the IF statement, everything works okay, but there is the extra little table cell at the end because I'm repeating the big table cell and the thin table cell for all three addresses on the line. It's not a HUGE issue, but I would would really like to have that thin table cell NOT entered if the `addr_count == 3` (I have tried `addr_count == '3'` and `addr_count == 3` and having quotes around the number didn't make any difference.

Here is the error I'm getting.

[image]

Does anyone know how to use an IF statement nested inside a FOR loop in python-docx-template?

Comment: Looks like it can't find one of your `endif` tags. Looking at the template, it looks as though there might be some mistakes in your second `if` statement. For example, the colon at the end of it is unnecessary. Second, there doesn't seem to be any content between the `if` and `endif`.

Comment: I had found one thread that said jinja needed a colon.  Maybe I need to add a space in the thin cell?  I know there isn't any content, but there is a table cell and that is what I want to print out ONLY if on the first or second time through the loop and not the 3rd.

Comment: Right, I see. As for the colon, your first if statement doesn't use one, and I assume that works fine? I doubt that's what's causing it though. It would be a lot easier to debug if instead of the actual table, the template was an XML or HTML table.

Comment: What happens if the `{% endif %}` goes in the small cell instead of after it?

Comment: That did it!  Please add an answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `{% endif %}` inside of the small cell instead of after it.

I'm not sure why this works, I actually spent a decent amount of time trying to puzzle out the logic. But if it works, it works.

Comment: I'm not sure why it works either, but like you said, if it works, it works and whoe cares?